# How do I create a simple folium map legend based on the marker colors and values?

Tags: google-maps-markers, legend, folium, folium-plugins

I have a folium map with three different colored markers which are based on cluster_labels from three bins:

df['cluster_label'] = pd.cut(df['column1'], 3, retbins=True, labels=[0,1,2])[0]

colors = ['lightgray', 'orange', 'red']

How do I create a simple folium map legend based on the marker colors and values like shown in the example image below?
[image]

Comment: A [request](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/528) on github might help you. Please check it out.[https://nbviewer.org/gist/talbertc-usgs/18f8901fc98f109f2b71156cf3ac81cd](https://nbviewer.org/gist/talbertc-usgs/18f8901fc98f109f2b71156cf3ac81cd)